# Pyspark parse datetime field with day and month names into timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I'm not even sure where to start.  I want to parse a column that is currently a string into a timestamp.  The records look like the following:

```text
Thu, 28 Jan 2021 02:54:17 +0000
```

What is the best way to parse this as a timestamp?  I wasn't even sure where to start since it's not a super common way to store dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably start from the docs [Datetime Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("Thu, 28 Jan 2021 02:54:17 +0000",)], ['timestamp'])

df.withColumn(
    "timestamp",
    F.to_timestamp("timestamp", "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
).show()

#+-------------------+
#|          timestamp|
#+-------------------+
#|2021-01-28 02:54:17|
#+-------------------+
```

However, since Spark version 3.0, you can no longer use some symbols like `E` while parsing to timestamp:

> Symbols of ‘E’, ‘F’, ‘q’ and ‘Q’ can only be used for datetime
> formatting, e.g. `date_format`. They are not allowed used for datetime
> parsing, e.g. `to_timestamp`.

You can either set the time parser to legacy:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
```

Or use some string functions to remove the day part from string before using `to_timestamp`:

```
df.withColumn(
    "timestamp",
    F.to_timestamp(F.split("timestamp", ",")[1], " dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
).show()
```